# Implementing a Kolmogorov-Smirnov permutation test

Tags: statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, permutation-test

I would like some advice on how to implement a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.

**This is a condensed version of my previous question -- any further detail can be provided if needed.**

I have data from *n* experimental trials. Each set consists of two paired time-series signals, for which I am calculating an informative "overlap" measure (a single summary value), based on some threshold value. I calculate this summary value for all *n* sets of data.

I would like to determine whether the distribution of these overlap values is non-random. The distribution of the data is not normal, and having read some details about different comparative tests of distributions, the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test seems most appropriate.

I'm hoping someone can give me advice on how to perform a permutation test using these data. My understanding is that this requires comparing the distribution of the actual data with those obtained from random combinations of the data, however, I'm uncertain of the procedure for implementing and interpreting the result. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: To do a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test you typically need a known reference distribution to compare against. If the overlap values were random, what would their distribution look like?

Comment: Randomising the overlap values produces something that looks quite different to the actual data (I'm not sure that the data fit an archetypal distribution particularly well). My thoughts were that I may be able to do a two-sample KS test, comparing the actual overlaps distribution with randomised ones. I could repeat my randomisation a number of times to collect many KS statistics; I'm not particularly confident however that this is a statistically robust way to proceed.

Comment: If your time series were independent, what would the overlap distribution look like? Would it have a mean of zero and be symmetric, for example?

Comment: No - the independent (i.e. randomised) overlap data are highly skewed, if anything like an exponential distribution. The actual overlaps distribution (of the paired time series) does not look like this, however. If anything it is more uniform.

Comment: You are describing what you are observing. I am asking what would the overlap data look like if the two time series were in some sense "equivalent." That is, they were independent, equally accurate, and with the same variance. If you can find the overlap distribution for that case, you have the reference distribution to use for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.

Comment: Hi soakley - forgive me but I'm not entirely sure I understand your question. The time series signals are acoustic data. I'm wondering how I could approximate them to find the reference distribution, as the data are non-stationary. What I imagine would be the case is that there would be few time series with large overlaps (unless by "equivalent" you mean also having the same mean), and many time series with little overlap.

Comment: Would a simple correlation check be useful? Suppose for each of your trials you estimate the correlation between the two time series. Using the null hypothesis that there is no correlation (overlap), you test that for each trial and analyze the results.

Comment: I have looked at various measures of correlation in the past, and it seems that correlation is not a particularly meaningful statistic for non-stationary time series (I'd be happy to hear about other techniques, however).  What I have done thus far is take many thousands of random combinations of the time series and computed their overlap distribution. When I run a two-sample KS test on this "meta" random set and the actual observations, it tells me to reject the null. My main concern is whether this is statistically "robust", and how can I interpret specific KS statistics.